# Apache Nifi: Pipe files using GetFile into ExecuteProcess

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a python script that takes in command line arguments to decrypt a file. The python command to be executed looks like this:

`python decrypt.py -f "file_to_decrypt.enc" -k "private_key_file.txt"`

I am trying to pick those files up using the `GetFile` processor in `NiFi` which does the job of picking them since I can see the filenames in the logs.

On the other hand, I have a `ExecuteProcess` process setup to run the python script as mentioned above. However I will need the filenames to be passed into the `ExecuteProcess`for the Python script to work. So my question is, how do I pipe the files from `GetFile`process into the `ExecuteProcess process` in `Apache NiFi`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`ExecuteStreamCommand`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) processor instead of `ExecuteProcess`. This processor accepts an incoming flowfile and can access attributes and content, whereas `ExecuteProcess` is a *source* processor and doesn't accept incoming flowfiles.

I don't know if you need `GetFile` (gets the content of the files); try `ListFile` and `RouteOnAttribute` to filter the two filenames you want. Merge the two successful listings into one flowfile with `MergeContent`, then use the `${filename}` attributes and expression language to populate the **command arguments** with `x.enc` and `y.txt`.

**Update**

I built [a template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/aacdb261461ab55f27d82c39e6f99085) that performs the following tasks:

1. Generates the example key file (not a valid key)
2. Generates the example encrypted data file (not valid cipher text)
3. Uses `ListFile`, `UpdateAttribute`, `RouteOnAttribute`, `MergeContent`, and `ExecuteStreamCommand` to perform the command-line Python decryption (mocked by `echo`)

*Note, this uses an expression language function `ifElse()` which is currently in NiFi `master` but is not yet released. It is part of the **1.2.0** release, but if you build from `master`, you can use it now.*

[image: NiFi ExecuteStreamCommand Template]

I still think `EncryptContent` or especially `ExecuteScript` is more compact, but this works.

Comment: Would that still be a good idea for very large files (50GB and more)?

Comment: This would be better because you're not loading the content of the files (which `GetFile` does) into NiFi at all. While NiFi does employ streaming to process large data and respect the heap, the content repository would still need to contain this data and performance would suffer.

Comment: So I am at a point where I have done the `MergeContent` step and now I need to unwrap that merged file in the `ExecuteStreamCommand` properties window. I looked at the usage file and attributes but to my understanding they don't talk about picking a file out of the merged file. When I do something like `${filename}`, it just prints the `Filename` of that merged file and I am not sure how to see its contents. So basically, how do I point to `x.enc` or `y.txt` from the merged flow file?

Comment: I added a template and screenshot that I built to explain it.

Comment: Awesome, I did not use the `ifElse()` but the whole things worked great when I just used `UpdateAttribute` and added the logic there. Thanks!

Comment: hi @summerNight - could you please explain how you did this? how did you get to pass the filename and then read the contents of the file as well in update attribute?